# Bolt CMS wrong paths on localhost xampp

Tags: php, twig, content-management-system, bolt-cms

I wanted to try out bold cms on my localhost.
I have installed bolt cms on localhost/test (subfolder)
The admin section works great, but when I try to visit the actual site all the paths are incorrectly. Bolts tries to load different css and js files like this:

```
/test/public/test/public/theme/base-2016/css/theme.css
```

While it should be

```
/test/public/theme/base-2016/css/theme.css
```

Im sure this is easy to fix but for some reason i cant find a fix for this

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put Bolt's `public` folder in your `test` folder. And put Bolt's other files one level up.

This is described [in the docs](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.2/installation/install-command-line#web-server-configuration) where you can also find answers to other web server questions regarding Bolt.